Flatten dynamic json payload string using pyspark
I have a scenario where I want to completely flatten string payload JSON data into separate columns and load it in a pyspark dataframe for further processing. The structure of raw data is NOT fixed, specifically the payload keeps varying.
Sample data:
{"id0":"d376","name":"data2","time_stamp":"2024-03-27", "payload":"{\"id\":\"d16\",\"time\":\"2000-01-01\",\"type\":\"XYZ\",\"detail\":{\"idx\":\"abc\",\"name\":\"abc\"},\"owner\":{\"id\":\"123\",\"communicate\":true},\"order\":{\"id\":\"2ff4973580\"},\"product\":{\"id4\":\"aiobfd8315\",\"name2\":\"fidoufodbf\"},\"transaction\":{\"amount\":90 ,\"category\":\"ugfiodfu\",\"create\":\"2024-03-27\",\"type\":\"idugoiuiofg\",\"gid\":\"d4ad\",\"id\":\"61c1025929e\",\"i_id\":\"3b6085400\",\"m_id\":\"1922c45\",\"prett\":null,\"pro_id\":\"a21b31f8315\",\"status\":\"waiting\",\"data2\":{\"create\":\"2000-01-01\",\"delivered\":yes,\"cla\":[\"irugreogeru\",\"fdijfdiog\"],\"id\":\"5542cefba043\",\"items\":[{\"quantity\":\"1\",\"price\":\"564\"}],\"approve\":null,\"tid\":\"6b1025929e\",\"update\":\"2001-02-02\"},\"t_extra\":{\"b_address\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"line1\":\"\",\"line2\":\"\",\"state\":\"\"},\"amount\":0,\"display\":{},\"id\":\"d06f5b502d64\",\"metadata\":{\"id4\":\"m044zi1gi\",\"email\":\"xyz@zyz.com\"},\"address\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"line1\":\"\",\"line2\":\"\",\"code\":\"\",\"state\":\"\"},\"update\":\"2000-01-01\"},\"token\":\"14849f64fc\",\"id5\":\"fbd2cceee\"},\"user\":{\"id\":\"fbdcceee\",\"number\":\"777777777\"},\"sum\":\"1\"}"}

I have multiple lines of JSON data in a file. The intention is to remove all the outer columns of the sample JSON, and flatten all the inner columns inside the payload string attribute of JSON.
The json is dynamic hence, going via the usual approach of defining the schema in StructType or ArrayType, etc., isn't very helpful and restricts approach (i.e defining schema for every events data), as the data is dynamic and all columns need flattening.
The closest I could get to solving my problem was below code, which still continues to wrap the payload part in a string in key-value pair than extracting them into individual columns.
Code:
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '.')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '.')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("App") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.json(path)
df = df.select('payload')

flatten_udf = udf(lambda json_str: flatten_json(json.loads(json_str)), MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
df_flattened = df.withColumn("payload", flatten_udf("payload"))
df_flattened.show(truncate=False)

Expectation is to have different df columns like:
id -> string column
time -> string column
type -> string column
detail.idx -> string column
detailname -> string column
owner.id -> string column
owner.communicate -> string column
... etc., all other columns


There is a nifty method schema_of_json in pyspark which derives the schema of json string and applies to the whole column.
So the following method to handly dynamic json payloads is as follows:

First take json_payload of first row of dataframe

Create a schema of the json_payload using schema_of_json

Then if all rows are correctly parsed, there would be no null value.
If there is a null value, it means those rows haven't been parsed correctly.
So we will conver those rows back to string. Then using .contains we will
check if null string is present in the string column.

This way we will have two dataframes. One dataframe will have correctly
parsed values. Another dataframe will have incorrectly parsed values.

Now we will repeat the process over incorrectly parsed dataframe.


Here's a sample script with custom data.
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("JsonPayloadDataFrame") \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("json_payload", StringType(), True)
])

data = [
    Row(json_payload='{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}'),
    Row(json_payload='{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}'),
    Row(json_payload='{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}'),
    Row(json_payload='{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}')
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(n=30, truncate=False)


wanted_df_list = []
df_looped = df

while not df_looped.isEmpty():
    print("USING SCHEMA FROM ONE ROW")
    current_string_repr = df_looped.limit(1).select(col("json_payload")).rdd.map(lambda x: x["json_payload"]).collect()[0]
    print(f"{current_string_repr=}")

    df_parsed = df_looped.withColumn("parsed_struct", from_json(col("json_payload"), schema_of_json(current_string_repr)))
    df_parsed.show(n=30, truncate=False)


    df_null_check = df_parsed.withColumn("null_present_str", col("parsed_struct").cast(StringType()))
    df_null_check.show(n=30, truncate=False)


    df_null_present = df_null_check.withColumn("null_present_bool", col("null_present_str").contains("null"))
    df_null_present.show(n=30, truncate=False)

    df_partial_correct = df_null_present.filter(col("null_present_bool") == False)
    df_partial_incorrect = df_null_present.filter(col("null_present_bool") == True)
    df_partial_correct.cache().show(n=30, truncate=False)
    df_partial_incorrect.cache().show(n=30, truncate=False)

    wanted_df_list.append(df_partial_correct)

    df_looped = df_partial_incorrect.drop("parsed_struct", "null_present_str", "null_present_bool")



for df_ele in wanted_df_list:
    df_ele.show(n=30, truncate=False)

Final Output :
+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|json_payload              |parsed_struct|null_present_str|null_present_bool|
+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}|{1, Alice}   |{1, Alice}      |false            |
+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+

+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                          |parsed_struct             |null_present_str          |null_present_bool|
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}|{true, 2, [spark, python]}|{true, 2, [spark, python]}|false            |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                             |parsed_struct      |null_present_str   |null_present_bool|
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}|{{30, New York}, 3}|{{30, New York}, 3}|false            |
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct                                   |null_present_str                                |null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|false            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+

Full Output :
root
 |-- json_payload: string (nullable = true)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}                                                                                   |
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}                                                       |
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

USING SCHEMA FROM ONE ROW
current_string_repr='{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}'
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}                                                                                   |{1, Alice}   |
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}                                                       |{2, NULL}    |
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{3, NULL}    |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{4, NULL}    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct|null_present_str|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
|{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}                                                                                   |{1, Alice}   |{1, Alice}      |
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}                                                       |{2, NULL}    |{2, null}       |
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{3, NULL}    |{3, null}       |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{4, NULL}    |{4, null}       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct|null_present_str|null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}                                                                                   |{1, Alice}   |{1, Alice}      |false            |
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}                                                       |{2, NULL}    |{2, null}       |true             |
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{3, NULL}    |{3, null}       |true             |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{4, NULL}    |{4, null}       |true             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+

+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|json_payload              |parsed_struct|null_present_str|null_present_bool|
+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}|{1, Alice}   |{1, Alice}      |false            |
+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct|null_present_str|null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}                                                       |{2, NULL}    |{2, null}       |true             |
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{3, NULL}    |{3, null}       |true             |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{4, NULL}    |{4, null}       |true             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+

USING SCHEMA FROM ONE ROW
current_string_repr='{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}'
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}                                                       |{true, 2, [spark, python]}|
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{NULL, 3, NULL}           |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{NULL, 4, NULL}           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct             |null_present_str          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}                                                       |{true, 2, [spark, python]}|{true, 2, [spark, python]}|
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{NULL, 3, NULL}           |{null, 3, null}           |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{NULL, 4, NULL}           |{null, 4, null}           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct             |null_present_str          |null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}                                                       |{true, 2, [spark, python]}|{true, 2, [spark, python]}|false            |
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{NULL, 3, NULL}           |{null, 3, null}           |true             |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{NULL, 4, NULL}           |{null, 4, null}           |true             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+

+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                          |parsed_struct             |null_present_str          |null_present_bool|
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}|{true, 2, [spark, python]}|{true, 2, [spark, python]}|false            |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct  |null_present_str|null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{NULL, 3, NULL}|{null, 3, null} |true             |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{NULL, 4, NULL}|{null, 4, null} |true             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+

USING SCHEMA FROM ONE ROW
current_string_repr='{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}'
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{{30, New York}, 3}|
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{NULL, 4}          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct      |null_present_str   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{{30, New York}, 3}|{{30, New York}, 3}|
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{NULL, 4}          |{null, 4}          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct      |null_present_str   |null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}                                                    |{{30, New York}, 3}|{{30, New York}, 3}|false            |
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{NULL, 4}          |{null, 4}          |true             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                             |parsed_struct      |null_present_str   |null_present_bool|
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}|{{30, New York}, 3}|{{30, New York}, 3}|false            |
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct|null_present_str|null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{NULL, 4}    |{null, 4}       |true             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+

USING SCHEMA FROM ONE ROW
current_string_repr='{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}'
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct                                   |null_present_str                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct                                   |null_present_str                                |null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|false            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct                                   |null_present_str                                |null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|false            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+

+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|json_payload|parsed_struct|null_present_str|null_present_bool|
+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+

+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|json_payload              |parsed_struct|null_present_str|null_present_bool|
+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}|{1, Alice}   |{1, Alice}      |false            |
+--------------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------+

+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                          |parsed_struct             |null_present_str          |null_present_bool|
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 2, "tags": ["spark", "python"], "active": true}|{true, 2, [spark, python]}|{true, 2, [spark, python]}|false            |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                             |parsed_struct      |null_present_str   |null_present_bool|
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 3, "details": {"age": 30, "location": "New York"}}|{{30, New York}, 3}|{{30, New York}, 3}|false            |
+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|json_payload                                                                                                 |parsed_struct                                   |null_present_str                                |null_present_bool|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|{"id": 4, "history": [{"date": "2023-01-01", "action": "login"}, {"date": "2023-01-02", "action": "logout"}]}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|{[{login, 2023-01-01}, {logout, 2023-01-02}], 4}|false            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------+

